# Evaluation of CASE/WHEN with single column changing values

Tags: sql, presto, case-when, trino

I am trying to convert some C# scripts that manipulate data within some Data Tables to a SQL (Presto DB) script that accomplishes the same thing.

The C# code will often change the value of a column depending on different conditions within the script. I am having trouble accomplishing the same task in SQL since C# is procedural and SQL is a single transaction.

```
SELECT
    IF(("ColumnA" = 'BS'), IF(("ColumnB" = '76'), "ColumnD", '2850'), '2850') "Result"
, CASE 
        WHEN ((("ColumnC" = 'IS') AND (("ColumnB" LIKE '125%') OR ("ColumnB" LIKE '126%'))) AND (CAST("ColumnD" AS Decimal(18,2)) < 2999)) THEN '2850' 
        WHEN ("ColumnC" = 'IS') AND (("ColumnB" LIKE '1%') OR ("ColumnB" LIKE '3%')) AND (CAST("ColumnD" AS Decimal(18,2)) = 2351) THEN '2351'
        WHEN ("ColumnC" = 'IS') AND (("ColumnB" LIKE '1%') OR ("ColumnB" LIKE '3%')) AND (CAST("ColumnD" AS Decimal(18,2)) = 2202) THEN '2202' 
        WHEN ("ColumnB" = '125999') THEN '2351' 
        WHEN ("ColumnB" = '126240') OR ("ColumnB" = '126245') THEN '2202' 
        WHEN ("ColumnB" = '125998') THEN '2351' 
        WHEN ("ColumnB" = '125997') THEN '2351'
    END
    ) "Result"
```

In a CASE .. WHEN clause will all CASEs be evaluated and the last one selected or is the first CASE that evaluates to TRUE selected and that is it for that column? If the latter I will need to figure out how to incorporate the first IF statement into the following CASE WHEN clause.

Comment: Your first `WHEN` clause does not have a `THEN`

Comment: @FrankPl Thanks for pointing that out. I copied the code as I was trying different ways to merge them. I have since corrected the code.

Comment: First time a when evaluates to true, you exit the case statement.

Comment: @webworm . . . If it helps, `case` is similar to `switch` in other programming languages, where the first match is the one that is returned (there is no "falling through" however).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, that does help. Is there a way to implement “falling through”?

Comment: @webworm . . . No.  A feature of `case` is that it stops at the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE`... `WHEN` is evaluated top down, and the `THEN` clause of the first `WHEN` that evaluates to true is the result. Further `WHEN` clauses are not evaluated.

You could translate this more or less to C# code by translating the first `WHEN` within the `CASE` to ´if(...)´ , all following `WHEN`s to `else if(...)`, and the the `THEN`s to `{ return ... }`.

And if you have nested `if`s, with or without `else` in C# which you want to translate to `CASE ... WHEN`, you can also nest `CASE WHEN`s, i. e. a `WHEN` clause can contain another `CASE ... WHEN`.